# How do I insert an image instead of using text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use a hyperlink to show an image instead of using text in the below starred text but I am not sure how to do it. Is it even possible to do this within JavaScript?? I have tried looking at other questions around these same parameters but I am not sure how to translate tose answers to my question. Thanks!

```
var user;
var choose = function(choice) {
    user = choice;
}

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}   
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
        else if (choice2 ==="scissors") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "ERROR!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting an image tag in place of your text?

Comment: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src=/image.png"/ alt="someimage">"`. Should probably do the trick, make sure to customize the src attribute of the image tag to the URL which your image is on.

Comment: using innerHTML to set text is weird and bad. use textContent.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to enter:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src='yourimg' alt='yourimgtext'/>"
```

where "yourimg" is the image you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Have `#result` be an image other than a text element:

```
<img id="result" src="..." alt="Rock Paper Scissors" />
```

Then change the `.src` of that image other than `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("result").src = ...;
```

Make sure you load in your 3 images first if they are large, otherwise you will be ok just changing the image source. Supposed they are named: `win.png`, `lose.png`, and `tie.png`. Then your code would look like this:

```
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    document.getElementById("result").src= "tie.png";
}
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        document.getElementById("result").src = "win.png";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").src = "lose.png";
    }
}
...
```